# error in the database - android

Tags: android, database

I tried one simple application in android... to store the database

but while add am getting error like below [image]

**Logcat error:**`06-11 14:27:32.157: ERROR/Database(523): Failure 1 (near "FROM": syntax error) on 0x2685c0 when preparing 'CREATE VIEW ViewTasks AS SELECT TaskTable.TaskID AS _id, TaskTable.TaskName, TaskTable.StartDate, TaskTable.EndDate, TaskTable.Desi, FROM TaskTable'.`

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


/*public DatabaseActivity(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}*/

static final String dbName="TaskDB";
static final String taskTable="TaskTable";
static final String colID="TaskID";
static final String colTask="TaskName";
static final String colStartDate="StartDate";
static final String colEndDate="EndDate";

static final String viewTasks="ViewTasks";  
static final String colDesi="Desi";



public DatabaseActivity(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null,66);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+taskTable+" ("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            colTask+" TEXT, "+colStartDate+" TEXT, "+colEndDate+" TEXT, "+colDesi+" TEXT)");



    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW "+viewTasks+
            " AS SELECT "+taskTable+"."+colID+" AS _id,"+
            " "+taskTable+"."+colTask+","+

            " "+taskTable+"."+colStartDate+","+
            " "+taskTable+"."+colEndDate+","+

            " "+taskTable+"."+colDesi+","+
            " FROM "+taskTable+""
            ); 


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+taskTable);

    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dept_id_trigger");
    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dept_id_trigger22");
    //db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fk_empdept_deptid");
    db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "+viewTasks);
    onCreate(db);
}



 void AddTask(Task tsk)
{


    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();       

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colTask, tsk.getTask());

    cv.put(colStartDate, tsk.getStartDate());
    cv.put(colEndDate, tsk.getEndDate());

    cv.put(colDesi, tsk.getDesi());
    //cv.put(colDept,2);
    //////////////////consider here ezhil
    //

    db.insert(taskTable, colTask, cv);

    db.close();

}

 Cursor getAllTasks()
 {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("Select "+colID+" as _id , "+colName+", "+colDesi+", "+colStartDate+", "+colEndDate+" from "+TaskTable, new String [] {});
    Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+viewTasks,null);
    return cur;

 }


 public Cursor getTskByDept(String Tsk)
 {   
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colTask,colDesi,colStartDate,colEndDate};
     Cursor c=db.query(viewTasks, columns, null, new String[]{Tsk}, null, null, null);
     return c;
 }   


 public int UpdateTsk(Task tsk)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
     cv.put(colTask, tsk.getTask());
     cv.put(colDesi, tsk.getDesi());
     cv.put(colStartDate, tsk.getStartDate());
     cv.put(colEndDate, tsk.getEndDate());
     return db.update(taskTable, cv, colID+"=?", new String []{String.valueOf(tsk.getID())});

 }

 public void DeleteTsk(Task tsk)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.delete(taskTable,colID+"=?", new String [] {String.valueOf(tsk.getID())});
     db.close();



 }


 }
```

Any one can help to me fri

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... +colDesi+","+             // problem is with this ,
" FROM "+taskTable+""
```

You've got an extra `,` there. Remove the one before the `FROM` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your sql statement - an extra comma in this line

```
 " "+taskTable+"."+colDesi+","+
```

should be

```
 " "+taskTable+"."+colDesi+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TaskTable.Desi, FROM TaskTable
```

The comma is to much. Remove it and it should work.